# Unsure of what analysis to use. Sample is too small for ANCOVA

Tags: covariance, small-sample, ancova

I am trying to analyze some preliminary data for a conference. I currently have two animal participants completing a series of tasks.
The tasks use different types of feedback (4 levels), which vary in the order they are completed (4 levels) that they occur. One animal has completed 20 tasks and the other has only completed 12, so I have unequal sizes.
My dependent variable is the total number of trials it takes them to complete the task (the criterion is when they reach 80% accuracy).
My independent variable is the feedback type (categorical variable).
I need to include the order as a covariate.
Because I have only 2 participants, I am reading that I cannot (or rather, should not) run an ANCOVA.
So I am looking for an alternative test that will work for such a small sample size with uneven groups. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am working in SPSS if that helps.